# use config file for constants in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, constants

I am using cibonfire, 
I have to use some constants in my programs which can be changed later.
So what I am doing is I am writing my config file inside `application/config/roles.php`
and using that config file in my modules to get that constants, but I am not getting the required result.

**SOLVED...**

Comment: Probably not loading the config file? Put 'routes.php' in your `$autoload['config']` array in config/autoload.php. (btw, those are not constants :))

Comment: @Narf : i have loaded confing file.. sorry I didn't mentioned that,problem edited.
and about the constants I am telling role_name may be changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved :)

In my view Page, I did this

`<?php $role_name = $this->config->item('roles.permission','roles'); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly these aren't constants, and if they were you couldn't change them later, hence the name constant!

Aside from that.. I believe you are not loading the config file.. try adding this to your controller file

```
$this->config->load('roles');
```

Comment: i have loaded confing file.. sorry I didn't mentioned that,problem edited.
and about the constants I am telling role_name may be changed